# Error al realizar slicing en python

Tags: python

Estoy intentando ejecutar esta línea de codigo

```
f =[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7,8,9]]
print(f[:,2])
```

pero me da el siguente error:

```
list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

cuando debería salir:

```
3
6
9
```

¿por qué no funciona?

Answer (score 1):

Cuando haces `print(f[:,2])` deberías quitar la coma para que no interprete que le estás pasando una tupla, es decir así `print(f[:2])`. De todas formas con esto le estarías pidiendo que te devuelva lo que hay dentro de `f` desde el inicio hasta el índice 2 y al tener listas anidadas te devolverá:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Por eso es necesario que recorras la lista `f` y en para cada uno de sus elementos imprimas el segundo.

Te dejo varios métodos que hacen lo que pides todos ellos partiendo de tu lista inicial:

`f = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]`:

**Un bucle sencillo:**

```
for e in f:
    print(e[2])
```

**Comprensión de listas:**

```
print('\n'.join([str(lst[2]) for lst in f]))
```

**Mediante map y lambda:**

```
print('\n'.join(map(lambda x: str(x[2]), f)))
```

Todos ellos te devolverán lo que dices:

```
3
6
9
```

Answer (score 0):

El error es porque usa coma cuando hace *slicing*. Python interpreta a esta coma como una `tuple`.

Para conseguir lo que quiere, primero tenemos que convertir:
`f =[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7,8,9]]` a una lista como aqui: `[3, 6, 9]` y luego imprimirla.
Hay dos metodos por el conversion:

**Metodo 1**
Usa *list comprehension*

```py
f2 = [ sublista[2] for sublista in f]
# f2 = [3, 6, 9]
```

**Metodo 2**

Usa el funcion *map*

```py
f2 = list ( map ( lambda sublista: sublista[2],f ))
# f2 = [3, 6, 9]
```

---

El ultimo paso, puede imprimir `f2` en esta manera:

```py
print(*f2,sep = "\n")
```

Comment: No necesitarías convertirlo a lista en el Método 2 si luego vas a imprimirlo con *f2

Answer (score 0):

Como habrás notado, ese tipo de indexación no funciona nativamente en Python. Pero me imagino que la estas ocupando inspirado en algún caso de uso que de hecho si funciona.

Puedes hacer funcionar ese tipo de indexación convirtiendo tu lista de listas en un `numpy.ndarray` de la siguiente manera:

```
import numpy as np
f = np.asarray([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7,8,9]])
print(f[:,2])  # imprime [3 6 9]
```